# Subjquery outside of Join

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

code downstairs will perfom query like this

```
SELECT anrede FROM `l_anrede` INNER JOIN `person` ON `l_anrede`.id = `person`.id_anrede
```

But I need a query like this:

```
  SELECT anrede FROM `l_anrede` INNER JOIN `person` ON `l_anrede`.id=`person`.id_anrede  WHERE
```

`person`.id IN(SELECT id_person FROM `bewerber` WHERE  `person`.id=`bewerber`.id);

Any ideas how to round out this code:

```html
$query = LAnrede::find();
/*
$subQuery = Bewerber::find()->select(['id_person'])
                ->from('bewerber')->where('person.id= bewerber.id');*/

$query->select('anrede')->from('l_anrede')->innerJoin('Person', 'l_anrede.id = person.id_anrede');
var_dump($query->one());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `->from('l_anrede')` if youre calling `LAnrede::find()` - query will select data from table associated with your model. To use subquery in `where()` method, try like this:

```
$query->andWhere(['person.id' => $subQuery]);
```